# how to zoom an image in canvas from center of canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to zoom in and out an image in canvas from the center of canvas.My Code zooms canvas by mouse position on canvas. What i want is to zoom image from center of canvas.
Here is complete code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
 canvas.width = 800; canvas.height = 600;
 var gkhead = new Image;
 window.onload = function(){  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  trackTransforms(ctx);
  function redraw(){
   // Clear the entire canvas
   var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
   var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
   ctx.clearRect(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y);

   // Alternatively:
   // ctx.save();
   // ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
   // ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   // ctx.restore();

   ctx.drawImage(gkhead,200,50);

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 6;
   ctx.moveTo(399,250);
   ctx.lineTo(474,256);
   ctx.stroke();

   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(4,2);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.moveTo(436,253);
   ctx.lineTo(437.5,233);
   ctx.stroke();

   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(438.5,223);
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#06c';
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0.05;
   for (var i=0;i<60;++i){
    ctx.rotate(6*i*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.moveTo(9,0);
    ctx.lineTo(10,0);
    ctx.rotate(-6*i*Math.PI/180);
   }
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.restore();

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
   ctx.arc(438.5,223,10,0,Math.PI*2);
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.restore();
   
  }
  redraw();
  
  var lastX=canvas.width/2, lastY=canvas.height/2;
  var dragStart,dragged;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
   document.body.style.mozUserSelect = document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
   lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
   lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
   dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
   dragged = false;
  },false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
   lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
   lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
   dragged = true;
   if (dragStart){
    var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
    ctx.translate(pt.x-dragStart.x,pt.y-dragStart.y);
    redraw();
   }
  },false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
   dragStart = null;
   if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1 );
  },false);

  var scaleFactor = 1.1;
  var zoom = function(clicks){
   var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
   ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
   var factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);
   ctx.scale(factor,factor);
   ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
   redraw();
  }

  var handleScroll = function(evt){
   var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta/40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
   if (delta) zoom(delta);
   return evt.preventDefault() && false;
  };
  canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);
 };
 gkhead.src = 'https://assets.teenvogue.com/photos/5ca368e87951d55db531218c/16:9/w_2560%2Cc_limit/hero-shawn-mendes-face-scar.jpg';
 
 // Adds ctx.getTransform() - returns an SVGMatrix
 // Adds ctx.transformedPoint(x,y) - returns an SVGPoint
 function trackTransforms(ctx){
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
  var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
  ctx.getTransform = function(){ return xform; };
  
  var savedTransforms = [];
  var save = ctx.save;
  ctx.save = function(){
   savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0,0));
   return save.call(ctx);
  };
  var restore = ctx.restore;
  ctx.restore = function(){
   xform = savedTransforms.pop();
   return restore.call(ctx);
  };

  var scale = ctx.scale;
  ctx.scale = function(sx,sy){
   xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx,sy);
   return scale.call(ctx,sx,sy);
  };
  var rotate = ctx.rotate;
  ctx.rotate = function(radians){
   xform = xform.rotate(radians*180/Math.PI);
   return rotate.call(ctx,radians);
  };
  var translate = ctx.translate;
  ctx.translate = function(dx,dy){
   xform = xform.translate(dx,dy);
   return translate.call(ctx,dx,dy);
  };
  var transform = ctx.transform;
  ctx.transform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
   var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
   m2.a=a; m2.b=b; m2.c=c; m2.d=d; m2.e=e; m2.f=f;
   xform = xform.multiply(m2);
   return transform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
  };
  var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
  ctx.setTransform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
   xform.a = a;
   xform.b = b;
   xform.c = c;
   xform.d = d;
   xform.e = e;
   xform.f = f;
   return setTransform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
  };
  var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
  ctx.transformedPoint = function(x,y){
   pt.x=x; pt.y=y;
   return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
  }
    }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

My Code zooms canvas by mouse position on canvas. What i want is to zoom image from center of canvas.
Thanks

Comment: **set**Transform might be better Anyway, can you include a complete example, also with the drawImage call.

Comment: setTransform is not working

Comment: "can you include a complete example, also with the drawImage call"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zoom to center of canvas, not to center of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070414/how-to-zoom-to-center-of-canvas-not-to-center-of-context)

Comment: @Kaiido I've edited my question. please check

Comment: @MaraBlack I didn't helped me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one:
[Rotating around an arbitrary point: HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936803/rotating-around-an-arbitrary-point-html5-canvas)

It offers a solution to your problem.